# Switching TabControl Templates depending on a property

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, datatrigger

I want to switch the ItemTemplate and the ContentTemplate of a TabControl.
Therefore I created two DataTemplates for the TabItem and two DataTemplates for the TabContent.
The templates should switch if the property IsRunningSession in CcLoginViewModel is true.
My problem is how to access this property in the DataTrigger.

Xaml:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LoginContentDataTemplate" x:Name="LoginTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:CcPlayerViewModel}">
        <local:CcLoginControl x:Name="LoginContentTemplate" DataContext="{Binding Login}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PlayerContentDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:CcPlayerViewModel}">
        <local:CcPlayerControl x:Name="PlayerContentDataTemplate" DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LoginContentDataTemplate}" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNewItemDataTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Login.IsRunningSession, Source={StaticResource PlayerTabItemTemplate}}" Value="True">  <-- Binding?
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PlayerContentDataTemplate}" />
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PlayerTabItemTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.Players/Login.IsRunningSession, ElementName=TabControlPlayers}" Value="False">  <-- Binding?
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource LoginContentDataTemplate}" />
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNewItemDataTemplate}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:CcMainViewModel x:Name="MainViewModel" />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="TabControlPlayers"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
                Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModels:

```
public class CcMainViewModel : CcViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<CcPlayerViewModel> Players { get; set; }
}

 public class CcPlayerViewModel : CcViewModelBase
{
    public CcLoginViewModel Login { get; set; }
}

public class CcLoginViewModel : CcViewModelBase
{
     public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set
        {
            if (password != value)
            {
                password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsRunningSession
    {
        get { return isRunningSession; }
        set
        {
            if (isRunningSession != value)
            {
                isRunningSession = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this : [DataTempalteSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTemplateSelector as Eldar has said. I have added few code snippets for you to start with.

**Step 1 -** Create a class by inheriting "DataTemplateSelector" like below,

```
public class TabControlContentTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate LoginContentDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate PlayerContentDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var obj = item as CcPlayerViewModel;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if(obj.Login.IsRunningSession)
            {
                return PlayerContentDataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return LoginContentDataTemplate;
    }
}
```

**Step 2 -** Create another class called "TabControlItemTemplateSelector" which inherits from "DataTemplateSelector" like below,

```
public class TabControlItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TabControlNewItemDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate PlayerTabItemTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var obj = item as CcPlayerViewModel;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if(obj.Login.IsRunningSession)
            {
                return PlayerTabItemTemplate;
            }
        }

        return TabControlNewItemDataTemplate ;
    }
}
```

**Step 3 -** Create TemplateSelectors in your .xaml like below,

```
<local:TabControlContentTemplateSelector x:Key="TabControlItemTemplateSelector"
  LoginContentDataTemplate="{StaticResource LoginContentDataTemplate}"
  PlayerContentDataTemplate="{StaticResource PlayerContentDataTemplate}" />

    <local:TabControlItemTemplateSelector x:Key="TabControlContentTemplateSelector"
      TabControlNewItemDataTemplate="{StaticResource TabControlNewItemDataTemplate}"
       PlayerTabItemTemplate="{StaticResource PlayerTabItemTemplate}" />
```

**Step 4 -** Use both the above TemplateSelectors and assign them to your TabControl like below in your .xaml

```
<TabControl Name="TabControlPlayers" ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TabControlItemTemplateSelector}"
            ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TabControlContentTemplateSelector}"/>
```

**Note :-** There is no use of your existing "TabControlStyle" in this case until you are doing some thing more for TabControl.

Your existing DataContext can still works fine.

Give a try and let us know in case if you are facing any further issues.